# How to make apache listen to a port and insert input received into mySQL?

Tags: mysql, apache

I have an `Apache` server (XAMPP) and I need to receive messages from a device which send messages to a specific `IP:port`. I woud like to configure `Apache` to listen to a port (let's say 443) and insert whatever messages receives there straight into mySQL (without php or anything else, just `Apache`). Let's call the database `DB` and the table to be inserted into `messages`, with the fields `number(INT, auto increment), content(VARCHAR(200))`.

Is that possible? Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you have to use apache ? Can't you just connect to MySQL server port ? Otherwise I'm not sure it is possible, but maybe I'm wrong...?

Comment: Hi. The device is a GPS tracker. It sends messages via GPRS to a IP:port combo. So, basically, it does not possess the ability to connect to a mySQL server.

Comment: Well as I'm not sure apache is able to directly insert into MySQL. What I will do (or what I do... ;) ) is send data from your GPS to IP_ADDRESS:5555 and a program would listen through a socket server (php, java, any language you like) on this port. This program inserts your data in MySQL. A `socket server` and `MySQL-insertion` are not very difficult to develop. Anyway, nice question. ;)

Comment: Actually, I already have a .php script that does that. But, since I will be using the Jelastic cloud solution to put my server online, I need something that does not uses PHP in order to save some money. It could be done with PHP but not in my case, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't know Jelastic Cloud Solution, sorry. So I don't know what you can do with that solution. Maybe someone else could help you for your problem. Just my thought : perhaps JCS is not what you need for what you want to do...